# How to use lightbox plug-in instead of window.open?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, lightbox, lightbox2

Somewhere in my JavaScript code, it opens a new window with open function/method.

```
window.open("sample_link");
```

But I want open neither tab nor window. I found a lot of examples lightbox plug-in which act on element. May I use function/method of lightbox plug-in instead of `open` function in my JavaScript code? (not in html file)

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't. This *plugin* deals with user interaction. If you want to open the *lightbox* programmatically, you may try:

```
<a  href="img/image-1.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="My caption">Image #1</a>

$('[data-lightbox]')[i].click();
// where i is the element you want
```